# Fixed width sidebar isn't the right size in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this simple HTML and I am using `tailwindcss`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-full" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <div id="app" class="h-full flex">
      <div class="w-[312px] bg-red-100">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">
          Sidebar
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full bg-green-100">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">
          Main
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, my sidebar's width is **not** 312px like I want it to be.

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing? Here is a [CodeSandbox too](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-cookies-i6p4d7?file=/index.html:0-664).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `flex-none` to prevent `div` from growing and shrinking. Like that.

```
 <div class="w-[312px] flex-none bg-red-100">
     <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">
          Sidebar
    </h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, can you please explain why the `flex-none` is necessary? In my mind, I was saying have the sidebar be 312px and whatever is left, give to the Main content. Was that not happening?

Comment: I wrote in answer it prevents from growing and shrinking. `flex-none` in css is `flex:none` which sets `flex-grow:0;` and `flex-shrink:0;`.

Comment: By default `flex-shrink` has value 1 so div can shrink.

Comment: @J86 when parent has `display:flex;` it works a little differently.